# Drupal language navigation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I want to show the language navigation icon on the header of my side. I use locale, i18 and content type translation. I am not interested to use module for language icon, I just want the link of the corresponding node and available languages. How can I achieve this? I am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 0):

If you use the module for the language icons, you will notice that when you are in a certain node, and you press on a different language, you will jump to the same node but in the other language.

In other words, you should change the language switcher from flags to whatever you want..